# How can I find each max element of three matrices as new matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Maybe the question is a little bit confused, I'll make an example below.

Let's say I have a 3 matrices `a`, `b`, `c`  with same size.

```
a = [2, 5; 6, 9];
b = [3, 3; 8, 1];
c = [5, 5; 2, 7];
```

How can I get the new matrix `max` with each max element in all three matrices?

```
max = [5, 5; 8, 9]
```

---

I know I could create logical matrix like `a>b` and then do the math, calc it out, is there any other more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the matrices into one `2x2x3` matrix using

```
d=cat(3,a,b,c)
```

and then use `max`-function to get your desired output:

```
maxValues=max(d,[],3)
```

The 3rd input to `max` defines along which dimension of the first input you want to find the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps.